# When do minimizers exist?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I'm trying to solve a problem set for my functional analysis course and I'm stuck at the following problem:

> Decide if the following problem has a minimizer
>
> Let $g\in C^0([0,1])$. Minimize $\|f-g\|_{L^\infty([0,1])}$ among all $f\in L^\infty([0,1])$ with $$\int_0^1\,f\,dx=0$$
>
> **Hint:** Consider $$\left|\int_0^1(g-f)\,dx\right|$$

I can't tell you something about what I've done so far, as I don' get the exercise. What are the conditions for such a problem to have a minimizer? What do I need to show? (Maybe there is no general scheme to apply here...?)

I don't have anything in my lecture notes on that..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

$$
\Bigl|\int_0^1g\,dx\Bigr|=\Bigl|\int_0^1(g-f)\,dx\Bigr|\le\int_0^1|g-f|\,dx\le\|g-f\|_\infty.
$$
Can you think of an $f$ such that

$$
\Bigl|\int_0^1g\,dx\Bigr|=\|g-f\|_\infty?
$$

Comment: Thank you, now I get how I should start with an exercise like this! Unfortunately the answer is no, I can't think of a function $f$ satisfying this. How would you argue?

Comment: It is quite easy: $f=g-\int_0^1g$.

Comment: Oh, that was really easy. Thank you again!